# Webhooks in Pinterest in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, pinterest

How can I trigger a function when a user post a comment on my app's pins? I am thinking of Webhooks but I can't find documentation about it in Pinterest.

I am successful in create ing pins using REST API but it is different in getting live feeds in Pinterest.

I am also using Nodejs and Meteor, so any package for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find out any solution to retrieve data by webhook?

Comment: Not yet. I'm waiting for the solutions.